# Function to get the total byte count from Response Object

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to write a simple function to calculate the total byte count from the response object , keep getting an error:

```
`reqwest::Response::bytes_stream` takes ownership of the receiver `self`, which moves `*response` .
```

Is there a way to get around this error? The intention is to iterate over chunk of bytes in the Response object and examine the size of each chunk

```rust
async fn calculate_byte_count(response: &Response) -> Result<usize, reqwest::Error> {
    let mut byte_count = 0;

    // Get the bytes stream from the response
    let mut body_stream = response.bytes_stream();

    // Iterate over the stream and accumulate the byte count
    while let Some(chunk) = body_stream.next().await {
        byte_count += chunk.unwrap().len();
    }

    Ok(byte_count)
}
```

Comment: Changing calculate_ byte_count to take ownership of response should allow this code to compile, i.e. calculate_byte_count(response : Response)

Comment: Instead of consuming the whole stream, you may want to look at `response.content_length()`.

Comment: @IanAsh - if the function is takes the ownership of the reqwest response object , any other function call is not possible example                                                                     let byte_count = calculate_byte_count(response);    
                  response.text().await;

Comment: @muddassir yes, obviously. But you asked how to make your function work and you didn't place any preconditions for calling the function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `bytes_stream` takes ownership of `Response`. The intent is that you parse headers etc to deal with the `Response`, then you (destructively) start working with the actual data (if any).

What do you want to do with the result of your function?

Sven [suggests `content_length` in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77924935/function-to-get-the-total-byte-count-from-response-object#comment137379202_77924935). This could work, but note the [caveats](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.Response.html#method.content_length) in the documentation. You should not use this function e.g. to check that there is enough space for the response in a buffer, since the actual byte count may be greater.

If you simply want to log the byte count and then continue processing, why not receive the bytes (simply with `response.bytes().await?`), then inspect the `.len()` of the result?

Comment: I am trying to see if there is a function example report_byte_count which can attached to the chunk method https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=17832f063a0d898b79b5035726e54b42